# Stacke different plots in a facet manner

Tags: r, ggplot2

To train with ggplot and to improve my skills in writing R functions I decided to build a series of functions that produces survival plots, with all kinds of extras. I managed to build a good working function for the basic survival plot, now I am getting to the extras. One thing I would like to do is an option that stacks an area plot of the number at risk at a given time point, on top of the survival plot. I would like it to look just like the `facet_grid` option of ggplot, but I did not manage to do it with this function. I do not want the two plots binded, like we can do with `grid.arrange`, but rather to have the same x-axis.

The following code produces the two (simplified) plots that I would like to stack on top of each other. I tried to do this with `facet_grid`, but I don't think the solution lies in this

```
library(survival)
library(ggplot2)
data(lung)
s <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ 1, data = lung)
dat <- data.frame(time = c(0, s$time),
                  surv = c(1, s$surv),
                  nr = c(s$n, s$n.risk))
pl1 <- ggplot(dat, aes(time, surv)) + geom_step()
```

[image]

```
pl2 <- ggplot(dat, aes(time, nr)) + geom_area()
```

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, melt your data to long format.

```
library(reshape2)
dat.long<-melt(dat,id.vars="time")
head(dat.long)
  time variable     value
1    0     surv 1.0000000
2    5     surv 0.9956140
3   11     surv 0.9824561
4   12     surv 0.9780702
5   13     surv 0.9692982
6   15     surv 0.9649123
```

Then use `subset()` to use only `surv` data in `geom_step()` and `nr` data in `geom_area()` and with `facet_grid()` you will get each plot in separate facet as `variable` is used to divide data for facetting and for subsetting. `scales="free_y"` will make pretty axis.

```
ggplot()+geom_step(data=subset(dat.long,variable=="surv"),aes(time,value))+
  geom_area(data=subset(dat.long,variable=="nr"),aes(time,value))+
  facet_grid(variable~.,scales="free_y")
```

[image]

Comment: Just for others' reference, the 'subset' function isn't necessary for such a simple filter.  `dat.long[dat.long$variable=="surv", ]` will produce the same results as `subset(dat.long,variable=="surv")`.  Neither approach is particularly superior, but it is nice to be aware of the options.