# GGPlot: Different chart types in facets?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to find a solution on how to stack 2 charts like facets.  One chart shows the data counts, while the second shows the percentage.

This is the post that inspired me: 
[Stacke different plots in a facet manner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16614860/ggplot-stacking-different-plots-in-a-facet-manner)

Currently, I create two independent charts:

```
set.seed(1)
trial.id <- sample(1:6, 1000, replace = TRUE, c(".35", ".25", ".2", ".15", ".04",   ".01"))
surv <- sample(0:1, 1000, replace = TRUE)

trial.df <- data.frame(cbind(trial.id, surv))

# chart with counts information
windows(height = 800, width = 1500)
plotEX1 <- ggplot(trial.df, aes(x = as.factor(trial.id) , fill = as.factor(surv))) + 
        geom_bar(stat = "bin") +
        ggtitle("Surival by Trial\n") +
        labs(x = "\nTrial", y = "Patients (#)\n") +
        scale_fill_discrete(name = "Survival") 
plotEX1

# chart with % information
windows(height = 800, width = 1500)
plotEX2 <- ggplot(trial.df, aes(x = as.factor(trial.id) , fill = as.factor(surv))) + 
        geom_bar(stat = "bin", position = "fill") +
        ggtitle("Surival by Trial\n") +
        labs(x = "\nTrial", y = "Patients (%)\n") +
        scale_fill_discrete(name = "Survival") 
plotEX2
```

trial.id represents the number of trials run.
surv represents the number of times a trial was successful.

plotEX1 show a count of how many trials were run, along with success rate.
plotEX2 is the same thing, but displays as a percent.

The goal is to see these two charts together, so it's easy for the reader to see what the trial counts were along with the percentage of success.

I think what's throwing me off is trying to melt the data.  I tried a couple things, but can't seem to get it to work.  Any help pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: You just need two copies of your data stacked via `rbind` and then create an artificial faceting variable.

Comment: `reshape2::melt(list(d, d))` and `lattice::make.groups(d, d)` are two convenient ways to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following our comments, I would probably do something like this:

```
new_dat <- melt(list(trial.df,trial.df),id.vars = 1:2)
new_dat$trial.id <- factor(new_dat$trial.id)
new_dat$surv <- factor(new_dat$surv)
ggplot() +
    facet_wrap(~L1,nrow = 2,scales = "free_y") + 
    geom_bar(data = subset(new_dat,L1 == 1),
             aes(x = trial.id , fill = surv),
             stat = "bin", 
             position = "fill") +
    geom_bar(data = subset(new_dat,L1 == 2),
             aes(x = trial.id , fill = surv),
             stat = "bin") +
    ggtitle("Surival by Trial\n") +
    labs(x = "\nTrial", y = "Patients (%)\n") +
    scale_fill_discrete(name = "Survival")
```

[image]

(And ignore the warnings.)

Comment: This is awesome!  I tried out your code my data and all the plots worked.  Makes them much easier to analyze.  A question I had though.. is it possible to manually set the y-axis limits on each facet?  Like .25 to .75, and 0 to 400?  Or is that not possible since scales are free_y?