# Stacking calculated plots in a facet manner

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

My question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16614860/ggplot-stacking-different-plots-in-a-facet-manner), in that I want the same result. However I don't think my data can be melted in the same way, as it's calculated from TRUE/FALSE values.

My data and graphs follow:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)
library(scales)
library(RColorBrewer)

#test dataframe
player <- c("a", "b", "a", "b", "c", 
            "a", "a", "b", "c", "b", 
            "c", "a", "c", "c", "a",
            "c", "c", "c", "c", "c",
            "c", "c", "c", "c", "c",
            "c", "c", "c", "c", "c",
            "b", "b", "b", "b")
is.winner <- c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
               FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
               TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE,
               TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,
               TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,
               FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,
               TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)

df <- data.frame(player, is.winner)

df$is.winner <- factor(df$is.winner, levels=c("TRUE", "FALSE")) #swap T/F bars

# Stacked wins and losses
aa <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=player, fill=is.winner)) +
       stat_bin(geom = "bar", position = "stack") +
       scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set2") +
       coord_flip()

# Win percentage
ab <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=player)) +
        geom_bar(aes(fill=is.winner),position='fill')+
        scale_y_continuous(labels=percent)+
        scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set2") +
        xlab("player") +
        ylab("win%") +
        coord_flip()

grid.arrange(aa,ab,ncol=2)
```

[image]

The goal is to easily be able to look at a players win count and win percentage, shown on different graphs above. I think the facet-style graph would be great, though I'm not sure if the way I've handled my data affects my ability to make use of that. Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Does it have to be facets per player? Or can separate plots also do the job?

Comment: I think the different scales here might be trouble in facets.

Comment: Either way, I was just hoping to get it looking like a facet graph, getting rid of the redundant x-axis labels and legends for example.

Comment: You could remove the legend from one of the plots and then keep using the grid.arrange you already have.

Comment: I think that's a good solution without using a facet-like graph. Maybe I'm looking too hard into trying to make the facet work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could make a dummy facetting variable,

```
d <- lattice::make.groups(first=df, second=df)

ggplot(data=d, aes(x=player, fill=is.winner)) +
  facet_grid(which~., scales="free") +
  geom_bar(position = "stack", data=subset(d, which=="first")) +
  geom_bar(position = 'fill', data=subset(d, which=="second")) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set2")
```

[image]

interestingly, flipping the coordinates produces an incorrect plot, at least with the dev version of ggplot2.

```
  last_plot() + coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: This looks very close to what I want. I'll try playing around with it and see if I can get something workable. Thanks.